# Email not send using Smtp in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, email, smtp, laravel-5.3

> i want to send an email to forgot password function congaing new password. Here is my code,

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.sendgrid.net
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=offrs
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

> here is my function for sending mail

```
  public function sendMail(Request $request){
        $new_key = str_random(10);
        $data = array();
        $data['email'] = $request->email;
        $data['key'] = $new_key;
        $checkUser = User::where('email','=',$request->email)->first();
        if($checkUser == null){
            return redirect()->back()->with('error','No User with this email exists in our record');
        }
        else{
            Mail::send('mail.forgetPasswordMail', ['data' => $data], function ($message) use ($data) {
                $message->from('raiafaculty@domain.com', 'RAIA Admin');
                $message->to(Input::get('email'))->subject('Your New Password');
            });
//            $useremail = $request->get('email');
//            $user = User::where('email', '=', $useremail)->first();
            $checkUser->password = bcrypt($new_key);
            $checkUser->save();

            return redirect()->route('login')->with('success','Please Check Your email for new password');
        }
    }
```

> it produces the error always.
>   (1/1) Swift_TransportException
>   Connection could not be established with host smtp.sendgrid.net [No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
>
> ## 10061]
>
> at Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer->initialize(array('protocol' => 'tcp', 'host' => 'smtp.sendgrid.net', 'port' => 587, 'timeout' => 30, 'blocking' => 1, 'tls' => true, 'type' => 1, 'stream_context_options' => array()))
>   in AbstractSmtpTransport.php (line 113)
>
> Help will be appreciated please.

Comment: You might want to change those smtp credentials if they're used on a live server. Also sending passwords via email is really insecure.

Comment: i will change the password scenario in future. the problem is email is not sending on local environment as well as on live server. i am using Xampp as local server and heroku as live server. can you help me on this?

Comment: is there any help?

Comment: Check your username and password, and also try without encryption

Comment: My issue has been solved. there is a port issue from networking department in my office.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code below

```
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your code, explaining _why_ you code change helps the OP (asker of the question).